# rails 3 - additional views in a different directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am look at upgrading our legacy rails 2 app to rails 3. One thing is that we have an additional set of view files in a different directory.
In rails 2 I had an initializer that did this:

```
ActionController::Base.view_paths.unshift File.join("#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/renderers", 'views')
```

How can I do a similar thing in rails 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you'd do it now:

```
SampleApplication::Application.config.paths.app.views << File.join( Rails.root, 'app', 'complementary_views' )
```

Comment: Thanks. This can go in the application.rb I guess too.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby on Rails v5.0 and later, there are helper methods to prepend and append view paths. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#view-paths